# Invalid c declaration that passes k&r grammar

Tags: c, declaration

On k&r 2nd edition p123, it shows the grammar of declarator
[image]

I've found similar syntax on c standard n1256
[image]

according to this `int foo()()()` is also a valid declarator (which is obviously not), what am I missing here?

ps: there's a [cdecl site](https://cdecl.org/?q=int%20foo%28%29%28%29%28%29) that deciphers c declarations to plain words, and it translates above decl to "declare foo as function returning function returning function returning int"

Comment: *`int foo()()()` is also valid declarator (which is obviously not)*  Why is that "obviously not" valid?  `int x = foo()()();` would call `foo`, which returns a second function, which is then called, which returns a third function, which is then called and returns an `int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's expression and conforms to expression syntax (6.5 in n1256), I'm asking about declaration syntax

Comment: You'd actually need to use function *pointers*, and that gets weird unless you use `typedef`.  So no, it's not "obviously not" valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int foo()();` is a *syntactically* valid declaration according to the grammar rules you quoted. However, it is *semantically* invalid; it fails the constraint in [6.7.6.3p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3) [C11/N1570; probably 6.7.5.3 in the older edition you've got].

> #### 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> ##### Constraints
>
> 1. A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array type.

This is a semantic rather than a syntactic rule because it was easier to write the standard that way.  Forbidding `T name ( ... ) ( ... )` syntactically might not even be *possible* in a [LR grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser). (C's syntax was designed to fit within LR(1) as much as possible; as I recall there are only a couple of places where it isn't.)  If it is possible, it would still make the definition of a *direct-declarator* much more complicated.  And `T name ( ... ) ( ... )` isn't the only way to [attempt to] declare a function whose return type is a function type.  A semantic constraint covers all the possibilities in one sentence.

The difference between semantic and syntactic rules only matters if you are writing a C parser yourself.  If you're just trying to understand what is and is not a valid C program, `int foo()();` is invalid either way.

If you're trying to understand what is and is not a valid C program *by reading the text of the C standard*, you should know that the C standard never says that a compiler *must* issue a hard error for something.  Failing that, implementers usually take the first sentence of 5.1.1.3 to define the line between warnings and errors:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any **syntax rule** or **constraint**

(boldface: my emphasis). So, you need to read the grammar rules and also the text of all the "constraints" sections.

Comment: Bravo champ, it's also denoted in 6.7.5.3 on n1256 :)